# What's the shortest way to integrate $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{7x^2+5}{x^4+6x^2+25}\, \mathrm{d}x$?

Tags: calculus, integration

What would be the shortest way to integrate this function from $$\int_0^{\infty}
\frac{7x^2+5}{x^4+6x^2+25}\, \mathrm{d}x$$

I used integration by partial fractions and got the right answer but twas quite lengthy. Wondering if there's a shorter way

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Hint: since the integrand's denominator is$$\begin{align}(x^2+5)^2-(2x)^2&=\prod_\pm(x^2\pm2x+5)\\&=\prod_\pm((x\pm1)^2+2^2),\end{align}$$you should try expressing the denominator as a linear combination of the four easily integrated functions$$\frac{1}{x^2\pm2x+5},\,\frac{x\pm1}{x^2\pm2x+5}.$$

Comment: I did this, and the solution was very long so I was wondering if there's another method

Answer (score 5):

Let $I$ denote the integral. Substitute $x = \sqrt{5}t$ to write

$$ I
= \sqrt{5} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{7t^2 + 1}{5t^4 + 6t^2 + 5} \, \mathrm{d}t
= \sqrt{5} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{7 + t^{-2}}{5t^2 + 6 + 5t^{-2}} \, \mathrm{d}t. \tag{1}
$$

Next, note that the substitution $t \mapsto t^{-1}$ yields

$$ I = \sqrt{5} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{7t^{-2} + 1}{5t^2 + 6 + 5t^{-2}} \, \mathrm{d}t. \tag{2} $$

Hence, averaging $\text{(1)}$ and $\text{(2)}$ gives

$$ I
= 4\sqrt{5} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1 + t^{-2}}{5t^2 + 6 + 5t^{-2}} \, \mathrm{d}t
= 4\sqrt{5} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1 + t^{-2}}{5(t - t^{-1})^2 + 16} \, \mathrm{d}t. $$

Finally, substitute $y = t - t^{-1}$ to get

$$ I
= 4\sqrt{5} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{5y^2 + 16}
= \left[ \arctan\biggl(\frac{\sqrt{5} y}{4}\biggr) \right]_{-\infty}^{\infty}
= \pi. $$

Answer (score 2):

$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^{\infty} \frac{7 x^2+5}{x^4+6 x^2+25} d x 
= & \int_0^{\infty} \frac{7+\frac{5}{x^2}}{x^2+\frac{25}{x^2}+6} d x \\
= & \int_0^{\infty} \frac{4\left(1+\frac{5}{x^2}\right)+3\left(1-\frac{5}{x^2}\right)}{x^2+\frac{25}{x^2}+6} d x \\
= & 4 \int_0^{\infty} \frac{d\left(x-\frac{5}{x}\right)}{\left(x-\frac{5}{x}\right)^2+16}+3 \int_0^{\infty} \frac{d\left(x+\frac{5}{x}\right)}{\left(x+\frac{5}{x}\right)^2-4} \\
= & {\left[\arctan \left(\frac{x-\frac{5}{x}}{4}\right)+\frac{3}{4} \ln \left|\frac{x+\frac{5}{x}-2}{x+\frac{5}{x}+2}\right|\right]_0^{\infty} } \\
= & \frac{\pi}{2}-\left(-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=\pi
\end{aligned}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Partial fraction decomposition does not seem to be too lengthy if you start with
$$\frac {7t+5 }{t^2+6t+25 }=\frac {7t+5 }{(t-a)(t-b)}$$ with $(a,b=-3\pm 4i)$
$$\frac {7t+5 }{(t-a)(t-b)}=\frac 1{a-b}\left(\frac{7a+5 }{t-a} -\frac{7b+5 }{t-b} \right)$$

Now, replace $t$ by $x^2$ to face two integrals
$$I(c)=\int \frac {dx}{x^2-c}=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{c}}\tanh ^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{c}}\right)$$
$$J(c)=\int_0^\infty \frac {dx}{x^2-c}=\frac{\pi}{2}   \sqrt{-\frac{1}{c}}$$
$$J(a)=\frac {2+i} 5 \qquad \text{and} \qquad J(b)=\frac {2-i} 5$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that $ x^4+6x^2+25=(x^2+3+4i)(x^2+3-4i)$
\begin{align}
\int_0^{\infty}
\frac{7x^2+5}{x^4+6x^2+25}dx
=& \ \Re \int_{0}^{\infty}
\frac{7 -4i }{x^2+3+4i}dx\\
= &\ \Re (2-3i)\tan^{-1}\frac x{\sqrt{3+4i}}\bigg|_0^\infty =\pi\\
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

If you know complex analysis, this is conceptually trivial, but the algebra is somewhat of a pain. Take a standard semi-circular contour on the upper half-plane. It can be shown easily that the integral vanishes on the semi-circular arc as its radius tends to infinity, so we're only left with the integral over the real line, which equals whatever we get by applying the residue theorem. Since the integrand is even, we have

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{7z^2+5}{z^4+6z^2+25}dz = 2\int_0^\infty \frac{7z^2+5}{z^4+6z^2+25}dz =2I$$

Since the denominator can be expressed a quadratic with respect to $z^2$, we can easily find the zeroes: the denominator has zeroes at $\pm (2i+1)$ in this contour and zeroes at $\pm(2i-1)$ in the lower half-plane.

We then have
\begin{align*}
 \frac{7z^2+5}{z^4+6z^2+25} &= \frac{7z^2+5}{(z-(2i+1))(z-(2i-1))(z-(1-2i))(z-(-1-2i))}\\
\end{align*}

At $z_1 = (2i+1)$, the residue is
$$\text{Res}_{z_1}=\frac{-16+28i}{-32+16i} = \frac{3}{4}-\frac{i}{2}$$
Similarly, at $z_2 = (-1+2i)$, the residue is
$$\text{Res}_{z_2} = -\frac{3}{4}-\frac{i}{2}$$

By the residue theorem, we have $2I = 2\pi i \sum\text{Res}_{z_i} = 2\pi$, and thus get

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{7x^2+5}{x^4+6x^2+25}dz  = \pi$$